# Django Inventory update function

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new Django and I'm working on a small project, I have two models Item and Stock. For Item model, I have a form where a user can select a product and choose its quantity he/she wants to purchase. If the customer selects product 1 and quantity 30, I want the function to subtract 30 from product1 in Stock model. How can this be implemented in views.py , I believe my views.py is incorrect.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    product_choices = (('product1', 'product1'),('product2','product2'),)
    product = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = product_choices)
    quantity_choices = (('30','30'),('60','60'),)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = quantity_choices)
    
class Stock(models.Model):
    product1 = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    product2 = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def checkout(request):
     item = Item.objects.all()
     stock = Stock.objects.all()
     form = ItemForm(request.POST or None)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         if item.product == 'product1' and item.quantity =='30':
          stock.product1 = stock.product1 - 30
          elif:
              if item.product == 'product1' and item.quantity =='60': 
               stock.product1 = stock.product1 - 60 
          else:
               return None
```

Comment: u can use filter function  instead of if condition

Comment: how please tell me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your code

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        item = Item.objects
        if item.filter(product = 'product1', quantity = 30):
            stockval = Stock.objects.values('product1')
            Stock.objects.update(product1 = stockval[0]['product1']-30)
        elif item.filter(product = 'product1', quantity = 60):

            stockval = Stock.objects.values('product1')
            Stock.objects.update(product1=stockval[0]['product1'] - 60)
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: Hey I guess there's a little problem in ur code , if I select 60 it deducts 30. .

Comment: change the quantiity value as integer

Comment: do you mean   change quantity = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = quantity_choices) to quantity = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100, choices = quantity_choices)

Comment: quantity_choices = (('30','30'),('60','60'),) changed to  quantity_choices = ((30,30),(60,60),)

Comment: lastly if i want to add more products would it be like  if ,elif for product 1 and then again if , elif for product 2 ?

Comment: truely said your project model stucture is worng you can create the stock model using the Item foreign key and one column but your model is totally wornged

Comment: so do you mean that I should create different models for each product and connect them all to item model ? Because I want to monitor the stock of each item

Comment: try this model structure

Comment: product_choices = (('product1', 'product1'), ('product2', 'product2'),)
quantity_choices = (('30', '30'), ('60', '60'),)
class Item(models.Model):
    productid = model.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=product_choices)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=quantity_choices)


class Stock(models.Model):
    StockId = model.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productID =  models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    productsDetails = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)

Comment: so the quantity will be deducted from productsDetails?

Comment: you can use the quantity column in stock model not item model